# nsis : How to insert background picture with nsdialog or function in MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

Tags: nsis, modern-ui, nsdialogs

my code is :

```
; DIMM_V2 Easy NSIS GUI Script 
!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT dimm_hide
!include "page1.nsdinc"
!include "page2.nsdinc"
!include "page3.nsdinc"
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE #  need to load custom exe 
!define MUI_UI_HEADERIMAGE ".\dimm_beta_img.exe"  ; dimm 1018 my bmp image ! 
; !define MUI_UI_HEADERIMAGE ".\modern.exe"  ; dimm 1018 my bmp image ! 

; dimm code for switching pages is is inside of pages .nsdinc


Page custom fnc_page1_Show
Page custom fnc_page2_Show
Page custom fnc_page3_Show
 ; Page custom dimm_hide
; !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
; !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
; !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
; BringToFront
; Destroy a window.
!macro DestroyWindow HWND IDC
    GetDlgItem $R0 ${HWND} ${IDC}
    System::Call `user32::DestroyWindow(i R0)`
!macroend
; 106 this page is Details Page
Function dimm_hide
; dimm   hide   ; need to hide 1256  /// 1037
!insertmacro DestroyWindow  $HWNDPARENT 1045     # dimm remove line from bottom
!insertmacro DestroyWindow  $HWNDPARENT 1256     # dimm remove line from bottom
!insertmacro DestroyWindow  $HWNDPARENT 1037     # dimm remove line from bottom
!insertmacro DestroyWindow  $HWNDPARENT 1028     # dimm remove line from bottom
FunctionEnd
Section
SectionEnd
```

Working with the NSIS installer and i want to set a static background image on the MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES page "MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES "
thx for any help.

*edit -  my others pages are already  full bg image, so i want to keep the same designt.

[image]

[image: edit - my others pages are already full bg image, so i want to keep the same desight .]

edit 2 : in this example it is green but it using "commctrl.nsh"
and so i dont know how to build all toghether .

```
code :
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "..\CommCtrl.nsh"
Caption "List View"
OutFile example1.exe
 Page custom CreatePage
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
Section Install
SectionEnd
Function CreatePage
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "List view control" "A SysListView32 control created by nsDialogs plugin"
  nsDialogs::Create 1018
  Pop $0
  StrCmp $0 error 0 +2
  Abort
  ${NSD_CreateListView} 0u 0u 300u 120u "ListView"
  Pop $1
  SendMessage $1 ${LVM_SETBKCOLOR}     0 0xC7EDCC # green bg for details page
  ; Insert a new item  ${NSD_LV_InsertItem} "hWnd" "iItem" "szText"
  ${NSD_LV_InsertItem} $1 0 "Item 0"
  ${NSD_LV_InsertItem} $1 1 "Item 1"
  nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use nsDialogs controls on other pages but you can use the image macros:

```
RequestExecutionLevel User
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "WinMessages.nsh"
!include "nsDialogs.nsh"

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW ConfigureInstFilesPage
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"


Function ConfigureInstFilesPage
FindWindow $1 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT ; Inner dialog
System::Call 'USER32::GetClientRect(pr1, @r2)'
System::Call '*$2(i.r6,i.r7,i.r3,i.r4)'
; Tweak $6, $7, $3 and $4 with IntOp and remove ${SS_CENTERIMAGE} if desired
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0, t"STATIC", p0, i ${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE}|${SS_BITMAP}|${SS_CENTERIMAGE}, ir6, ir7, ir3, ir4, pr1, p0, p0, p0)p.r5'
File "/OName=$Pluginsdir\ifp.bmp" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Header\win.bmp"
${NSD_SetBitmap} $5 "$Pluginsdir\ifp.bmp" $6
FunctionEnd 

Section
Sleep 1234
SectionEnd
```

NSIS was never designed to support full background images. The best option is probably to use [Graphical Installer](http://graphical-installer.com/web/) but it is possible to hack something up yourself:

```
RequestExecutionLevel User
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "WinMessages.nsh"
!include "nsDialogs.nsh"


#!define MUI_HEADER_TRANSPARENT_TEXT ; Set this if you don't want header text
!define MUI_TEXTCOLOR 000066
!define MUI_BGCOLOR 667788
!define TEXTCOLOR 0x${MUI_TEXTCOLOR}
#!define BGCOLOR "0x${MUI_BGCOLOR}"
!define BGCOLOR Transparent ; Setting this to "Transparent" only works partially and requires some hacks...

!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT GuiInit
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW ConfigureInstFilesPage
Page custom fnc_page1_Create
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
Page custom fnc_page1_Create
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
BrandingText " "

Function GuiInit
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 0x4E8
ShowWindow $0 0
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 0x404
ShowWindow $0 0
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 0x40b
ShowWindow $0 0
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 0x40c
ShowWindow $0 0
ShowWindow $mui.Header.Background 0
ShowWindow $mui.Header.Image 0
StrCpy $1 $HWNDPARENT
System::Call 'USER32::GetClientRect(pr1, @r2)'
System::Call '*$2(i.r6,i.r7,i.r3,i.r4)'
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0, t"STATIC", p0, i ${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE}|${SS_BITMAP}|${WS_CLIPSIBLINGS}, ir6, ir7, ir3, ir4, pr1, p0, p0, p0)p.r5'
File "/OName=$Pluginsdir\ifp.bmp" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Header\win.bmp"
LoadAndSetImage /STRINGID /RESIZETOFIT $5 0 0x10 "$Pluginsdir\ifp.bmp" $6
!if ${BGCOLOR} == Transparent
    ${NSD_AddExStyle} $mui.Header.Text ${WS_EX_TRANSPARENT}
    ${NSD_AddExStyle} $mui.Header.SubText ${WS_EX_TRANSPARENT}
!endif
FunctionEnd

!macro FixTransparentText
!if ${BGCOLOR} == Transparent
    System::Call 'USER32::RedrawWindow(p$HWNDPARENT,p0,p0,i4|1|512|128)'
!endif
!macroend

!macro PageInit
SetCtlColors $mui.Header.Text ${TEXTCOLOR} ${BGCOLOR}
SetCtlColors $mui.Header.SubText ${TEXTCOLOR} ${BGCOLOR}
FindWindow $1 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT ; Inner dialog
SetCtlColors $1 ${TEXTCOLOR} transparent
!insertmacro FixTransparentText
!macroend


Function fnc_page1_Create
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${If} $0 == error
Abort
${EndIf}
SetCtlColors $0 ${TEXTCOLOR} transparent
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Hello, welcome to nsDialogs!"
Pop $0
SetCtlColors $0 ${TEXTCOLOR} transparent
${NSD_CreateText} 0 13u 100% 30u "Type something here..."
Pop $0
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Blah" "Blah blah blah"
!insertmacro PageInit
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd


Function ConfigureInstFilesPage
!insertmacro PageInit
SetCtlColors $mui.InstFilesPage.Text ${TEXTCOLOR} ${BGCOLOR}
FunctionEnd


Section
DetailPrint Hello
Sleep 1234
SectionEnd

Section "-LastSectionToFixRedrawBug"
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "" ""
!insertmacro FixTransparentText
SectionEnd
```

Comment: thx for your reply , please see my post i have uploaded second picture , for showing my actual state , and i want to keep the same thing on next page.

Comment: I was on the point of buying graphical designer for nsis, but i have found some bugs, when you hover mouse on text buttons or radio buttons so that is huge bug for payed version

I can tell you more this is bug is present even in installer"GraphicalInstaller-NSIS-2022.2-Trial.exe",so it is not very cool for a payed version .

So i will build something myself free & working,and yes it is possible , im already at 80 % at Success.

Comment: WS_CLIPSIBLINGS - im using it already in dialog designer , if i apply your solution my labels "Page 1 and Page 2 "  are gone , because it's using  "WS_CLIPSIBLINGS" how to deal with it ?  and the same question for details page when you click "show details" - it is possible to make it transparent ?

Comment: I don't know how to make the InstFIles page log window transparent.

Comment: !define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_COLORS "transparent 77CCEB" ;Two colors

Comment: @Andrers, it is possible to have some function ( transparent page)  but for "MUI_PAGE_Directory" i have one of working but it is fot mui and not for mui2 , thx

Comment: There should not be a big difference for the dir page with MUI 1 and 2

Comment: warning the command  "/RESIZETOFIT" can render your image very ugly .some times it's better to remove this switch .

Comment: @DIMM_V2 Yes, or at least just fit the width or the height, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Working examle for "Directory Page" Full Transparent

```
;working examle for "Directory Page" Full Transparent /// DIMM_V2
!include "MUI2.nsh"
; Local bitmap path.
!define BITMAP_FILE res.bmp
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Installer Settings
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name "Background Bitmap"
OutFile "bgbitmap.exe"
ShowInstDetails show
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Modern UI Settings
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

; !define MUI_UI ".\dimm_beta_img.exe" ;The interface file with the dialog resources. Change this if you have made your own customized UI.


; !define MUI_HEADERIMAGE #  это отвечает за большое окно  
; !define MUI_UI_HEADERIMAGE ".\dimm_beta_img.exe" # измененный ехе     ; dimm 1018 my bmp image ! 
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_BGCOLOR CDCDCD  # gray color of Destination Folder
!define BGCOLOR Transparent ; Setting this to "Transparent" only works partially and requires some hacks...
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT MyGUIInit
!define MUI_TEXTCOLOR ffffff #  white : ffffff
!define MUI_BGCOLOR Transparent # back upper side must be transparent
DirText "$\r" # псевдо затирание!   /// hide text in directory page 
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_DESTINATION "Install Folder"
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Definitions
  InstallDir "$temp"
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Var hBitmap
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Pages
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW DirectoryPageShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
 ; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Macros
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Destroy a window.
!macro DestroyWindow HWND IDC
  GetDlgItem $R0 ${HWND} ${IDC}
  System::Call `user32::DestroyWindow(i R0)`
!macroend

; Give window transparent background.
!macro SetTransparent HWND IDC
    GetDlgItem $R0 ${HWND} ${IDC}
    SetCtlColors $R0 0x444444 transparent
!macroend


!macro setwhite HWND IDC
  GetDlgItem $R0 ${HWND} ${IDC}
  SetCtlColors $R0 ffffff transparent  # set text color here  ==> white -  ffffff   gray ,  transparent
!macroend
 
 
; Refresh window.
!macro RefreshWindow HWND IDC
  GetDlgItem $R0 ${HWND} ${IDC}
  ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_HIDE}
  ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_SHOW}
!macroend
 ; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Macros
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Functions
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Function MyGUIInit
  ; Extract bitmap image.
  InitPluginsDir
  ReserveFile `${BITMAP_FILE}`
  File `/ONAME=$PLUGINSDIR\bg.bmp` `${BITMAP_FILE}`
  System::Call `user32::GetClientRect(i $HWNDPARENT, i R0)`
  System::Free $R0
  ; Create bitmap control.
  System::Call `kernel32::GetModuleHandle(i 0) i.R3`
  System::Call `user32::CreateWindowEx(i 0, t "STATIC", t "", i ${SS_BITMAP}|${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE}, i 0, i 0, i R1, i R2, i $HWNDPARENT, i,i R3, i 0) i.R1`
  System::Call `user32::SetWindowPos(i R1, i , i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0, i })`
  ; Set the bitmap.
  System::Call `user32::LoadImage(i 0, t "$PLUGINSDIR\bg.bmp", i ${IMAGE_BITMAP}, i 0, i 0, i ${LR_CREATEDIBSECTION}|${LR_LOADFROMFILE}) i.s`
  Pop $hBitmap
  SendMessage $R1 ${STM_SETIMAGE} ${IMAGE_BITMAP} $hBitmap
FunctionEnd
; Refresh parent window controls.
; Has to be done for some controls if they have a transparent background.
Function RefreshParentControls
  !insertmacro RefreshWindow $HWNDPARENT 1020
  !insertmacro RefreshWindow $HWNDPARENT 1019
  !insertmacro RefreshWindow $HWNDPARENT 1256
  !insertmacro RefreshWindow $HWNDPARENT 1024
  !insertmacro RefreshWindow $HWNDPARENT 1023
FunctionEnd

; from page dir
; DirectoryPage "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
; DirectoryPage.Text $mui.DirectoryPage               1006
; DirectoryPage.DirectoryBox $mui.DirectoryPage       1020
; DirectoryPage.Directory $mui.DirectoryPage          1019
; DirectoryPage.BrowseButton $mui.DirectoryPage       1001
; DirectoryPage.SpaceRequired $mui.DirectoryPage      1023
; DirectoryPage.SpaceAvailable $mui.DirectoryPage     1024
  

; For directory page.
Function DirectoryPageShow
SetCtlColors $mui.DirectoryPage.title 0xFFFFFF transparent # Set Transparent page bg
;Set transparent backgrounds.
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
!insertmacro setwhite $0 1256 # SpaceRequired 
!insertmacro setwhite $0 1023  # SpaceRequired  
!insertmacro SetTransparent $0 1001 # dimm this is working
!insertmacro SetTransparent $0 1008 # dimm this is working
!insertmacro SetTransparent $0 1001
!insertmacro setwhite $0 1024 # space availbe  
!insertmacro SetTransparent $0 1008
!insertmacro SetTransparent $0 1006  # middle bg 
; !insertmacro SetTransparent $0 1020  # this is label of Dest. Folder
SendMessage $R0 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 STR: # hide label "Directory Folder"


; Remove unwanted controls.
!insertmacro DestroyWindow $HWNDPARENT 1023 # remove line here  working 
!insertmacro DestroyWindow $HWNDPARENT 1020 # remove line here  working 
!insertmacro DestroyWindow $HWNDPARENT 1256 # remove line here  working 
!insertmacro DestroyWindow $HWNDPARENT 1028 # remove line here  working
!insertmacro DestroyWindow $HWNDPARENT 1039 # remove line here working


 
; Refresh controls.
Call RefreshParentControls
FunctionEnd
 

; Free loaded resources.
Function .onGUIEnd
  ; Destroy the bitmap.
  ; System::Call `gdi32::DeleteObject(i s)` $hBitmap
FunctionEnd
 
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Dummy section
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Section "Dummy Section"
SectionEnd
```

[image]